# Grab iFrame Code dynamicly from a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a div with unique id and inside of this i have a youtube iframe code.
I am trying to develop a sticky div and when the users scrolls down to fade out the default div that holds the youtube iframed video and move it to a this new sticky div and start play.

So far i am developing the code bellow:

Inside body:

```
<div id="newdiv" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="currentplayer">
    <iframe width="600" height="338" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/avl5zgk3KH4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The code so far for the sticky div is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#currentplayer').offset().top;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#currentplayer').hide();
            $('#newdiv').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '35px',
                width: '310px'
            });
            $('#newdiv').fadeIn("fast");
        } else {
            $('#newdiv').fadeOut("fast");
            $('#currentplayer').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

So how is possible when the user scrolls up to move the current iframe inside the new div with id="newdiv" and resume play?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery appendTo should do the trick ...

```
$( "#currentdiv iframe" ).appendTo( $( "#newdiv" ) );
```

Comment: once iframe gets pulled from dom and re-inserted it will reload , won't maintain state

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery command `.html` to both get and set the html contents of a div.

However, I imagine that copying the iframe to a new div will mean the video will play from the beginning.  If that is a problem, then you should try and achieve this by changing the currentplayer css instead.  Perhaps have a div on the outside of currentplayer with a set height and use this to detect the position the user is on the page instead.

If that is not possible, then look into using the YouTube api, as you will then be able to access data like how much of the video has played and tell the second video area to start playing from this point.